# how to get how many open connections are there with sequelize 6 and postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I need to log the active and idle connections in each pod. I can't find in the sequelize documentation how to get the open connections

Comment: Query `pg_stat_activity` in the database?

Comment: yes, but this way I get all the connections from all the connected microservices. And I only need the number of connections of a microservice.

Comment: Query it by database name, by client IP address or by `application_name`. If none of that suffices, set `application_name` different in each microservice.

Answer (score 0):

Have each microservice set the `application_name` parameter with a statement like

```
SET application_name = 'microservice 1';
```

Then you can get the connection counts with

```
SELECT application_name, count(*)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE datnane IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY application_name;
```

Comment: How set `application_name` parameter to a nodejs application that uses Sequelize?

Comment: Issue the `SET` SQL statement.